# Batch rename files that match a rule

Tags: macos, shell, file-io, automator

I've got a folder from an old iOS project with lots of files structures similar to

```
image.png
image@2x.png
another-image.png
another-image@2x.png
```

However as the project now only needs the @2x.png images I've deleted all the files without @2x in the names.

However I'm now wondering how I can easily remove the @2x from all the filenames (theres approx 300 images)

The environment I'm on is OSX Mavericks, so any automator/terminal commands would be fine.

Answer (score 4):

```
for name in *@2x*; do mv $name ${name%@2x*}${name#*@2x}; done
```

Answer (score 0):

Consideration has been given for names containing spaces:

```
IFS=$'\n'
for f in $(find . -name \*@2x.png)
do
    newf="$(echo "$f" | sed s/@2x//)"
    mv "$f" "$newf"
done
```